# Ошибка при вставление данных в таблицу - Incorrect datetime value: 'NOW()'

Tags: mysql, sql

Когда вставляю данные в таблицу выдаётся следующая ошибка

```
Incorrect datetime value: 'NOW()' for column 'date_stopped' at row 1
```

Вот запрос

```
INSERT INTO ArchiveSubscriptions (id,msisdn,service_id,status,date_started,date_stopped,lang_id,profile_id,trial_days,tarif_status,activation_channel,deactivation_channel,last_charge_date,last_success_charge_date) VALUES('3','351914254433','100','2','2022-03-06 20:11:19','NOW()','3','','3','0','USSD','USSD',NULL,NULL);
```

Структура Таблицы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Может кто-то пж помочь или хотя-бы подсказать где я ошибаюсь

Comment: А зачем ты пытаешься вставить **строку** в колонку с датой?

Comment: спасибо, уже заметил, затупил :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При вставление данных в таблицу ты в колонку `date_stopped` передаёшь строку, а он принимает `datetime`. Поэтому передавать NOW() нужно без кавычек. Вот так нужно:

```
INSERT INTO ArchiveSubscriptions 
(id,msisdn,service_id,status,date_started,date_stopped,lang_id,profile_id,trial_days,tarif_status,activation_channel,deactivation_channel,last_charge_date,last_success_charge_date) 
VALUES('3','351914254433','100','2','2022-03-06 20:11:19', NOW(),'3','','3','0','USSD','USSD',NULL,NULL);
```